# Window Service not accessing external method

Tags: c#, .net, service

I m a bit new here . I am trying to learn window service from microsoft tutorial :
    [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt39148a(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt39148a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

I installed  and run it perfectly ..event logs are working Fine ...Now I am trying access One function in another c# project (named ASMSFetch) which has reference to the service project  ...

This is Service .cs file code

```
 public partial class MyNewService : ServiceBase
    {
        public MyNewService()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {

            ASMSFetch.Program.UpdateSMS();
        }


    }
```

and ASMSFetch Project Program.cs

```
 public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            UpdateSMS();

        }



        public static void UpdateSMS()
        {

            Console.WriteLine("UpdateSMS started");
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
```

But that "UpdateSMS started" messege doesnot appear when I install and run the service  from computer management -> service section ..

I tried to search it .but couldnt able to find reasonable .
Any suggestion would be helpful ...

Comment: Have you checked the Windows Event Logs to ensure your service isn't crashing, or having some other issue?

Comment: yes...event logs are working Fine ...

Answer (score 0):

See here...
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/76477d2t(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/76477d2t%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Under item #4 - you need to call your service. If the above is all your code, then you're missing that and nothing is actually starting the service. When the OS starts your service, all it does is call the Main() method, just like any other EXE.

You need to add a line like this:

```
 System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase.Run(new MyNewService());
```